# WPF Click Once / current info

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I'm still ticked at MS handling of Silverlight for enterprise LOB applications.  The only thing that I can think of that has a similar deployment strategy is WPF click once.

I've searched and everything on this site is a couple of years old at best.  I can't seem to find a lot on MS sites as well.

Can somebody point me to current information, books, etc. on the subject? Will it be support by MS for a few years to come? Any plans to update it? (Roadmap details?)

Answer (score 0):

The 'current' information is the same as it has always been and can be found in the expected place on MSDN. You can find out all about ClickOnce from the following link:

> [ClickOnce Deployment Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx)

I have been using it for years without issue, so I can confirm that it works and works well.